# Silverlight Isolation file saving in particular folder issue.

Tags: file-upload, silverlight-4.0, download, isolatedstorage

I am working on silverlight application and I want to save my file in a particular folder through savefile dialog box. But I am not able to save it.

And also I want to open it, let's say through open - dialog box.

How can I do it?

Thanks..

Comment: Can you clarify what you need? Is it to save / open files in an arbitrary location in the user's computer, or is it to save / open file in a subdirectory of the application isolated storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open/save files using the open/save file dialogs even outside the isolated storage for the application. Search "silverlight savefiledialog" and you'll find many examples.

Comment: Ok This is fine but my question is I have Isolated storage and I am savig file as an type of class it will goes to some silverlight root directory so I am able to openthe dialogbox but it will save to the silverlight directory.

Comment: To go through the isolated storage (IS) you don't need to use the SaveFileDialog; if you do, then the user may be able to select a directory out of the IS, so if you don't want it, then you shouldn't use the SaveFileDialog.

Comment: without selecting a directory it is working properly but in my case I want to save in a perticular directory.